# Verify Text on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'd like to verify some text on a webpage but seems that Selenium IDE is not finding it.

I want to find the word "AMS" on a page, and I'm using like this:

command: **verifyTextPresent** // target: **AMS** // value:

Here's a screenshoot to make it easier to understand (sorry about the black squares, they're sensitive information):

http://oi39.tinypic.com/w0a4m.jpg

Comment: verifyTextPresent working fine at our end. Please paste here the error which you observed while executing 'verifyTextPresent'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check for **Global AMS Director** whole value.

OR

1. Select AMS value using mouse and after that right click on and select "verifyTextPresent AMS" command
2. It will add your command in Selenium IDE and it should work fine.

I tried that on "Selenium Wiki page" and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I was facing. Please try *VerifyText* instead. It worked for me